# What is "this Point" in this Java problem?

Tags: java

I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring this out from Tim Buchalka's class on Udemy.  It refers to calculating 2 points in 2D space.  They keep referring to "this Point" and no matter how many times I ask, I cannot seem to get a straight answer about what "this Point" is.  Is it "Point first" always, or is it the most recently entered `Point`?  Could "Point second" become "this Point"?  What is "Point(x,y)"?  Is it always "Point second" or could it be something else or a changeable point?  If so, how do you define which becomes "this Point" or "Point(x,y)"?  All I need to know is how to know which point becomes "this Point" and which becomes "Point(x,y)".

> Point
> You have to represent a point in 2D space. Write a class with the name Point. The class needs two fields (instance variables) with name x and y of type int.
>
> The class needs to have two constructors. The first constructor does not have any parameters (no-arg constructor). The second constructor has parameters x and y of type int and it needs to initialize the fields.
>
> Write the following methods (instance methods):
>
> Method named getX without any parameters, it needs to return the value of x field.
>
> Method named getY without any parameters, it needs to return the value of y field.
>
> Method named setX with one parameter of type int, it needs to set the value of the x field.
>
> Method named setY with one parameter of type int, it needs to set the value of the y field.
>
> Method named distance without any parameters, it needs to return the distance between this Point and Point 0,0 as double.
>
> Method named distance with two parameters x, y both of type int, it needs to return the distance between this Point and Point x,y as double.
>
> Method named distance with parameter another of type Point, it needs to return the distance between this Point and another Point as double.
>
> How to find the distance between two points?
> To find a distance between points A(xA,yA) and B(xB,yB), we use the formula:
>
> d(A,B)=√ (xB − xA) * (xB - xA) + (yB − yA) * (yB - yA)
>
> Where √ represents square root.

Here is the test code:

> TEST CODE:

> ```
> Point first = new Point(6, 5); Point second = new Point(3, 1);
> System.out.println("distance(0,0)= " + first.distance());
> System.out.println("distance(second)= " + first.distance(second));
> System.out.println("distance(2,2)= " + first.distance(2, 2));
> Point point = new Point();
> System.out.println("distance()= " + point.distance());
> ```
>
> OUTPUT
>
> ```
> distance(0,0)= 7.810249675906654
> distance(second)= 5.0
> distance(2,2)= 5.0
> distance()= 0.0
> ```

See above. All I have written so far is below.  Pretty basic and not complete.

```java
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point() {
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distance() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Point` is a class, every time the instructions say "this Point" refers to the current instance of `Point`. For instance, if comparing the distance to `Point other`, you'll be subtracting the x/y values between the points with logic such as `other.getX() - this.x`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with any non-static method is that there's a special instance of the class that's the instance the method has been called on.  So when you write something like `myPoint.setX(3);`, you're calling `setX` on a particular instance of `Point` - that is, a particular `Point` object.

When the author says "this Point", they mean the instance that a method was called on.  So you'll write a method that looks like

```
public double distance(Point other) {
    // Some code here to calculate the distance between the instance
    // on which the method was called, and the instance called `other`.
}
```

and you might call it with a line of code like

```
double distance = firstPoint.distance(secondPoint);
```

Incidentally, there's a static method called `hypot` in the `Math` class that can do most of the calculation for you.  You might like to check [the Javadoc for that method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#hypot(double,double)).

Answer (score 0):

by using `java.awt.geom.Point2D` Package,you can easily write this code:

```
public double distance(
    double xa, 
    double ya, 
    double xb, 
    double yb) {        
    return Point2D.distance(xa, ya, xb, yb);
}
```